# npm ERR! nospc ENOSPC: no space left on device

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, jenkins, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I launced an ec2 instance of 28G volume and set up codepipeline. In build stage of aws-codepipeline I set up jenkins and on execution it gives following error on build stage while executing `npm install`

`npm ERR! nospc ENOSPC: no space left on device, write`

output of `df -h`

```
udev            985M     0  985M   0% /dev
tmpfs           200M  776K  199M   1% /run
/dev/xvda1       28G   28G  3.2M 100% /
tmpfs           996M     0  996M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           996M     0  996M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       18M   18M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/1335
/dev/loop1       89M   89M     0 100% /snap/core/7169
tmpfs           200M     0  200M   0% /run/user/111
tmpfs           200M     0  200M   0% /run/user/1000
```

Output of `free -m`

```
Mem:           1991         455         978           1         557        1351
Swap:             0           0           0
```

Output of `sudo du -h / | sort -hr | head -n10`

````
du: cannot access '/proc/1917/fd/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/1917/fdinfo/3': No such file or directory
2.5G    /
1.4G    /usr
721M    /usr/lib
579M    /var
441M    /var/lib
374M    /usr/share
326M    /snap
268M    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
253M    /snap/core/7169
253M    /snap/core```
````

Answer (score 2):

I found that the whole space of 28G was filled by the log files of jenkins `/var/logs/jenkins`.
I deleted the whole logs but still was facing same issue.
`df -h` was still showing that 100% of volume is used.

On running `lsof | grep deleted` I found that although these files are deleted but is still open by some process.

Then I killed all the process using `killall -9 java` and it fixed the error.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Do this:

```
rm -r node_modules/*
```

Then run `npm install` again